# How to use the XSLT fn:document function in Saxon-HE?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, saxon

How to use the XSLT fn:document function in Saxon-HE? i know .net can use "EnableDocumentFunction" by Xml Resolver. How/Where to insert XmlResolver in my below coding.

```
#region "saxon"
public static StringWriter saxonmethod(string sourceFile, Stream XSLT)
{
    Processor processor = new Processor();

    TextReader stringReader = new StringReader(sourceFile);
    XmlTextReader reader2 = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
    reader2.XmlResolver = null;// Load the source document
    XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(reader2);


    // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
    XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(XSLT).Load();
    transformer.InputXmlResolver = null;

    // Set the root node of the source document to be the initial context node
    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

    // Create a serializer
    StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();//serializer.SetOutputWriter(Console.Out);
    serializer.SetOutputWriter(s);

    // Transform the source XML to System.out.
    transformer.Run(serializer);
    return s;
}

#endregion
```

Thanks in Adavance. Saran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply to remove the `transformer.InputXmlResolver = null;` line, then I think `document/doc` should work. If not, then you can set `transformer.InputXmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have one more doubt the related question, my xslt used "exslt" so that i got it Saxon.Api.DynamicError, "Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://exslt.org/common}node-set(). There is no Saxon extension function with the local name node-set", please help to resolve.

Comment: @saravanans, that is a completely different problem, you should have asked a new question for it. But with XSLT 2.0 there is no need for that function so simply replace any use of e.g. `exsl:node-set($var)` with e.g. `$var`.

Comment: Hi Margin, Thank you very much for great help, Its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your stylesheet is doing, or how it is failing, so we're working rather in the dark here. My guess is that your argument to the document() call is a relative URI and it is failing because there is either no known base URI, or an incorrect base URI. By default document() uses the base URI of the stylesheet, and that's unknown when the stylesheet is loaded from a Stream, so you need to set the BaseUri property on the XsltCompiler.

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick reply.

My XML <body><CaseRefLink href="file:///D:/.....xml">.

My Xslt calling document() function but never working, its working fine for me when transform from Oxygen:     <xsl:for-each select="document(ancestor::xhtml:body/xhtml:CaseRefLink/@href)//xhtml:ref[@refNo=$ParaNo]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::xhtml:p/xhtml:CaseRef"/></xsl:for-each>

Comment: OK, you're calling document() supplying a node as argument, in which case it's the base URI of that node that counts. So you need to set the BaseUri property of the DocumentBuilder used to build the source document. Alternatively, don't bother creating an XmlTextReader, just Build() directly from the file, then Saxon will know the base URI as the location of that file.

Comment: Hi Michael Kay, I have one more doubt the related question, my xslt used "exslt" so that i got it Saxon.Api.DynamicError, "Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://exslt.org/common}node-set(). There is no Saxon extension function with the local name node-set", please help to resolve.

Comment: @saravanans, please try to be a bit more organized. That looks like a completely unrelated question, so please raise it as a new question. Explain what you were trying to achieve, what code you wrote, what XSLT processor and version you were using, and how it failed.